# T-SQL escape quote character

Tags: t-sql, escaping

NOTE: It's probably a duplicate but I can't find working answer.

Following is what i'm trying todo, notice a `'` in the value. How do I fix this?

`INSERT INTO [pugraider].[dbo].[Realms]([Name]) VALUES('Aman'Thul')`

I use MS SQL Server Management Studio 2008.

EDIT: I'm writing a script to populate a lookup table (ID<->Name).

Comment: For the future readers, this will allow your code to work but you should be using parameterized queries.  This is really only acceptable in the MS SSMS environment the author is using.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This will work:-

```
INSERT INTO [pugraider].[dbo].[Realms]([Name]) VALUES('Aman''Thul')
```

Ordinarily the only reason to have such hardcoded values in T-SQL is in DB construction code such as initialising look up tables.

Otherwise this code might be a result of string concatenation to build up some T-SQL from some input source.  If that is the case its worth finding ways to avoid it since it can open your application to SQL injection attacks.