# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException on RichTextBox

Tags: sql, string, vb.net, visual-studio

I have written an application that w/ a Rich Textbox for Suggestion box.
I have the datatype in **VB.Net as String** to be inserted into a SQL table column with a datatype **nvarchar**. The problem I'm facing is that I am able to enter all characters in the textbox except a colon('). Can anyone please direct me on how I can allow the textbox to except the colon(') as data so it will flush into the database?

```
Error: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ')'.'
```

The code:

```
Public Class Form1_AnsaldoSTSSuggestions 
Dim EmployeeID As String = Convert.ToUInt32(EmployeeID) 
Dim FirstName As String       
Dim LastName As String        
Dim Department As String      
Dim Phone As String = Convert.ToUInt32(Phone)       
Dim Email As String           
Dim Suggestion As String
```

Comment: you need to double the single quotes, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2029307/t-sql-escape-quote-character

Comment: Yes. Use parameters. This will allow you to inserted whatever chars in your strings and protect you from sql injection attacks.

Comment: Hi Zohar  could you provide me an example of what you mean in my case?

Comment: You can search for vb.net parameterized sql server queries. That should get you started.

Comment: Ok will do. Thank you Zo. Will dig deeper into this.

Comment: Do you know why I could be getting syntax error 
cmd.Parameters.Add("@RichTextBox1") cmd.Parameters("@RichTextBox1").Value = RichTextBox1_SuggestionBox.Text

cmd.CommandText = $"insert into Suggestions(EmployeeID,FirstName,LastName,Department,Phone,Email,ContactMethod,Suggestion,SuggestionDate) values  ("{"@TextBox6"}","{StrConv(@TextBox1, VbStrConv.ProperCase)}","{StrConv(TextBox2, VbStrConv.ProperCase)}","{StrConv(@TextBox3, VbStrConv.ProperCase)}", "{@TextBox4}","{@TextBox5}","{@ComboBox1}","{@RichTextBox1}","{@Label7}")"

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean apostrophe (') not colon (:). You can replace the apostrophe with two apostrophes, but it also sounds like you are dynamically building a SQL string which opens you up to SQL injection attacks. Do some research on sanitizing SQL input data.

Comment: Yes you are correct an apostrophe. Brain is fried from thinking so hard. I will take your advise on the research. Thank you Bill Hall

Answer (score 0):

please use the replace function when you get the value from Richtextbox.
Example:

```
Dim strRichTextValue=RichTextBox1.Text
strRichTextValue=strRichTextValue.Replace("'","''") 'simple solution with Replace
```

Let me know the progress.
Regards,

Comment: I added this line of code. It throws be another error. System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Comment: Did you replace the name of RichTextBox1 with your own richtextbox? Plz do so and also check that richtextbox has Text property or Value property to get its contents. here is a bit change in my previous code snippet:                    
Dim strRichTextValue as string
strRichTextValue=RichTextBox1.Text

'if richtextbox has Value property to get contents,use following line
'strRichTextValue=RichTextBox1.Value 

'if richtextbox has Content property to get contents,use following line
'strRichTextValue=RichTextBox1.Content 

strRichTextValue=strRichTextValue.Replace("'","''") 'you r done