# SQL Server. dynamic query error while using aggregate function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am little bit new to SQL. I am trying to run below shown dynamic query

```
SET @SQL ='
select Distinct count(*) TotalCount,
    sum(case when ap.FormStatus = ''open'' then 1 else 0 end) AS Totalopenstatus,
    sum(case when ap.FormStatus = ''Pending'' then 1 else 0 end) AS TotalPendingstatus,
    sum(case when ap.FormStatus = ''Awaiting L1 Review'' then 1 else 0 end) AS TotalAssociates,
    sum(case when ap.FormStatus = ''Awaiting L2 Review'' then 1 else 0 end) AS TotalL1reviews,
    sum(case when ap.FormStatus = ''Awaiting Delivery Head'' then 1 else 0 end) AS TotalL2reviews
    from [dbo].[Appraisals] ap
    LEFT join [dbo].[FinalReviewClosures] fi ON ap.FinalReviewClosure_Id = fi.id
    join [dbo].[employees] emp ON fi.Employee_Id = emp.id
where fi.FinancialYear ='+@FinancialYear +'  AND ap.Quarter = '+@Quarter+' '
```

but I get this error:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_GetReviewStatus, Line 51 [Batch Start Line 11]
> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value

Code:

```
select Distinct count(*) TotalCount,
    sum(case when ap.FormStatus = 'open' then 1 else 0 end) AS Totalopenstatus,
    sum(case when ap.FormStatus = 'Pending' then 1 else 0 end) AS TotalPendingstatus,
    sum(case when ap.FormStatus = 'Awaiting L1 Review' then 1 else 0 end) AS TotalAssociates,
    sum(case when ap.FormStatus = 'Awaiting L2 Review' then 1 else 0 end) AS TotalL1reviews,
    sum(case when ap.FormStatus = 'Awaiting Delivery Head' then 1 else 0 end) AS TotalL2reviews
    from [dbo].[Appraisals] ap
    LEFT join [dbo].[FinalReviewClosures] fi ON ap.FinalReviewClosure_Id = fi.id
    join [dbo].[employees] emp ON fi.Employee_Id = emp.id
where fi.FinancialYear =2020-2021  AND ap.Quarter = Q3  AND emp.office = ' to data type int.
```

Please help me fix this problem.

Comment: I guess there are some quotes missing and the target is `where fi.FinancialYear = '2020-2021'`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2029307/t-sql-escape-quote-character) on how to escape quotes in T-SQL.

Comment: **Warning** what you have appears to be wide open to injection. Don't inject your parameters, **parametrise** them (they *are* parameters after all).

Comment: They aren't missing quotes, @Sander, as the value shouldn't be being injected in the first place.

Comment: Why is this statement "dynamic" anyway? There's nothing dynamic about it. Just use a parametrised non-dynamic query.

Comment: i am sorry i got the issue (financial year && Quarter ) are nvarchar

Comment: You have no group by clause - so your query (when it works) will generate a single row. No reason to use DISTINCT.

Comment: They don't need one, @SMor , they have no columns no in an aggregate function.

Comment: @Larnu THAT'S my point.

Comment: I miss read, apologies, @SMor . Though a `DISTINCT` with a `GROUP BY` is always an indicator that the `GROUP BY` clause is wrong as the `GROUP BY` will already be separating the data into *distinct* groups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason what you have is failing is as has been mentioned. You are injecting values instead of parametrising and these values are creating invalid syntax in your "dynamic" query. (Read on to see why I say "dynamic".)

`fi.FinancialYear ='+@FinancialYear +'` becomes `fi.FinancialYear =2020-2021`, which is effectively `fi.FinancialYear = -1` (what year is `-1`?). This will cause an error if `fi.FinancialYear` isn't able to be converted implicitly to an `int`.

`ap.Quarter = '+@Quarter` becomes `ap.Quarter = Q3` and unless you have a column called `Q3` then you're going to get an invalid column error.

If you *are* using dynamic SQL then **never** inject unsanitised values; quote your object names using `QUOTENAME` and parametrise your parameters (which you can do with `sys.sp_executesql`).

What you have, however, has no need to be a "dynamic" query; there is nothing dynamic about it. Just use a non-dynamic parametrised query and the query will work fine:

```sql
SELECT --DISTINCT --Not needed, as the query will only return 1 row.
                  --Even if you did have a GROUP BY the DISTINCT isn't needed,
                  --as the GROUP BY will already put the data in DISTINCT sets.
       COUNT(*) AS TotalCount,
       SUM(CASE WHEN ap.FormStatus = 'open' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Totalopenstatus,
       SUM(CASE WHEN ap.FormStatus = 'Pending' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TotalPendingstatus,
       SUM(CASE WHEN ap.FormStatus = 'Awaiting L1 Review' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TotalAssociates,
       SUM(CASE WHEN ap.FormStatus = 'Awaiting L2 Review' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TotalL1reviews,
       SUM(CASE WHEN ap.FormStatus = 'Awaiting Delivery Head' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TotalL2reviews
FROM [dbo].[Appraisals] ap
     LEFT JOIN [dbo].[FinalReviewClosures] fi ON ap.FinalReviewClosure_Id = fi.id
     JOIN [dbo].[employees] emp ON fi.Employee_Id = emp.id
WHERE fi.FinancialYear = @FinancialYear --I assume fi.FinancialYear and @FinancialYear have the same data type?
  AND ap.Quarter = @Quarter; --I assume ap.Quarter and @Quarter have the same data type?
```

Answer (score 0):

Where clause should be

```
where fi.FinancialYear ='2020-2021'  AND ap.Quarter = 'Q3'  AND emp.office = ' to data type int.'
```

instead of

```
where fi.FinancialYear =2020-2021  AND ap.Quarter = Q3  AND emp.office = ' to data type int.
```

Please also let me know the data type of @financialYear and @Quarter